# jquery get msg of specific class only

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, dom

In the following i am trying to track the last element that is getting inserted into `p-msg-class` class, but i see the alert a lot of times since the there are other elements inserted dynamically to `.middle-ui,.flt-rt,.content-ht` . how can i track only `p-msg-class` and make the alert stop for all the other html inserted dynamically

```
  $('.middle-ui,.flt-rt,.content-ht').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
     if($(this).find(".visitor-msg-cont").last().find(".p-msg-class").length > 0)
     {
        alert($(this).find('.visitor-msg-cont').last().find('.p-msg-class').last().html());
     }
  });
```

Comment: did you try `find('.p-msg-class:last')`?

Comment: yes but how how will it solve the problem everytime for ex:class="new" is inserted i get the alert..

Comment: oh I see what the problem is now.  So, you have to find out what the inserted elements class is, and if it is `p-msg-class` then do the alert.  Is the new element always appended to the end?

Comment: its always appended to visitor-msg-cont and basically its a chat data..so i have to get the latest chat

Comment: yes i need to alert the last value of p-msg-class when ever it is inserted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok something like this could work. Get the class of the last element added and check if it is "p-msg-class".

```
$('.middle-ui,.flt-rt,.content-ht').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
    var newElement = $(this).find(".visitor-msg-cont").last().children().last().attr("class");
    if(newElement === "p-msg-class")        
    {
    alert($(this).find('.visitor-msg-cont').last().find('.p-msg-class').last().html());
    }
});
```

if you know the child elements will be all div or p then you can use `children(div:last)` or something like that.

Not sure this will work but it could point you in the right direction.

Comment: hmnn i tried this.but this is stll alerting for all the elements inserted into `.middle-ui,.flt-rt,.content-ht`

Answer (score 0):

without seeing more of your html structure, it's difficult to answer the question. I'm assuming that you're dynamically inserting DOM elements that may or may not have the class .p-msg-class.

Instead of searching for the last inserted .p-msg-class element, why not throw the alert as you're inserting it? Something like this (untested):

```
$('.middle-ui,.flt-rt,.content-ht').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
    if($(event).target.hasClass('p-msg-class'))
    {
        alert($(event).target.html());
    }
});
```